# Confusion in the object and array for Node.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
    var dataArray = [];

    switch (request_url.query.group) {
        case 'returning': 
            dataArray = {};
            var returning = _.filter(result, function(result) {
                return (result.sessions.length > 1) ? true : false;
            });
            //Am I setting the object dataArray here?
            dataArray.returning = returning.length; 
            //Am I setting the array dataArray here?
            dataArray['new'] = result.length - returning.length; 
            break;
```

I have confusion regarding dataArray here. The first line of code declares an array and in the switch case an object of the same name is declared. What is the 'new' and 'returning' values set and whom do it respectively belong to, the array or the object?
Also, is object a super class of array in Node.js?

Comment: There's only one declaration, on the first line.

Comment: There is a declaration of dataArray in the switch case

Comment: no there isn't. There's an *assignment*.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the 'new' and 'returning' values set and whom do it respectively belong to, the array or the object?

They'll *belong* to the `Object`. The `Array` is only referenced by `dataArray` up until this line:

```
dataArray = {};
```

After that, `dataArray` will only be a reference the `Object` while the `Array` would become unreachable and available for garbage collection.

---

Note: If you were wanting `dataArray` to be an "*`Array` of `Object`s*," you can assign the `Object` to an index of `dataArray`:

```
dataArray[0] = {};
```

And set the properties similarly:

```
dataArray[0].returning = ...;
dataArray[0]['new'] = ...;
```

---

> Also, is object a super class of array in Node.js?

Yes. `Array`s inherit from `Object`s because [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) is an `Object`. MDN has a good summary of the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), which is JavaScript's inheritance model.